# Parsing a 2D QVariantMap

Tags: c++, json, qt, dictionary, qvariant

Using QJson to parse this data:

```
"ShelveId": {
  "0": {
    "BeBoardId": {
      "0": {
        "connectionId": "board0", .... followed by more data
```

I'd like to traverse this table quicker than doing this. All maps are QVariantMaps:

```
map_BeBoardId = map_ShelveId["0"].toMap();

map_BeBoardId = map_BeBoardId["BeBoardId"].toMap();

auto temp = map_BeBoardId["0"].toMap();
m_connectionId = temp["connectionId"].toString();

qDebug() << m_connectionId;
```

Which works and returns me my connectionId "board0" correctly.

What I'd like to do instead is something like this:

```
map_BeBoardId = map_ShelveId["0"].toMap();

map_BeBoardId = map_BeBoardId["BeBoardId", "0"].toMap();

m_connectionId = map_BeBoardId["connectionId"].toString();

qDebug() << m_connectionId;
```

This returns me an empty connectionId.

And no, I can't use lists here as sometimes we may have a Shelve Id of "1" and "4" depending on what is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the weary traveller, after all sorts of attempts, this is what I came up with:

```
auto temp = map_BeBoardId.value("0").toMap().value("connectionId").toString();
```

A bit verbose, yes, anyone else come up with a better solution then then can post it.